# How to fork a repo you have on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

If I have a repo for trying something in a book, and then I decided to make it a repo for a certain component, how could I fork the repo so as to remove a lot of other things and only make it a repo for the component?

GitHub doesn't allow users to fork a repo that they own.

So what is a good way to do it?  I can only think of `git clone` this repo in Bash, or `cp -R` to make a copy, and then change the `remote` `origin` and add it to a different repo I create on GitHub.

P.S. For this case I wouldn't want to make it a branch, because I want to make it a "standard repo" of a component for other people to look at, and also for changing the `github.com` to `githubbox.com` in the URL so that codesandbox.io can import the code and make it an online ReactJS demo.

Comment: I would go with the copy. Not sure if needed, but I would also clear git history after copying, by removing the `.git` folder from the copy. Then make file changes/cleanup. Then attach to new remote repo.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using different branches. Why do you have to do it in a different repository?

Create a different repository with a different name and do all the stuff that you normally do to a forked repository.

Comment: a different branch won't do in this case... I want to make it like a "standard repo" of a component for other people to look at

Comment: I see. Here is a blog post about it: https://deanmalone.net/post/how-to-fork-your-own-repo-on-github/ . Does it work for you?

Comment: isn't it very similar to what I suggested I could do?